# runaway processes named i686 and x86_64

Tags: 14.04

Yesterday morning I found my machine was running three processes that were pegging three cores. Two processes were named "i686" and one was "x86_64", as displayed by system monitor panel. Figuring they were associated with the kernel, I didn't kill them, but instead rebooted. That took care of it for the rest of the day. Now this morning I come in and find those three processes again, pegging three cores. All three processes started around 1 AM and were still running at 8 AM. I don't have a screen saver running. When I run ps -ef | grep < PID>, I get the following:

```
UID      PID    PPID  C STIME TTY      TIME     CMD
admin    15071     1 96 01:09 ?        07:02:51 /usr/sbi  <-- "x86-64"
admin    15080     1 96 01:09 ?        07:11:57 /usr/s    <-- "i686"
admin    10274     1 97 Oct06 ?        11:39:06 /usr/s    <-- "i686"
```

Anybody else seeing this? How can I determine what is launching it? What is /usr/s ?

EDIT: I manually killed the processes and my machine is running fine, so they aren't critical system processes.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: What string are you grepping for? The `/usr/s` is likely just a truncated version of the directory name `/usr/sbin`: to see the full command you can try something like `ps -e -opid= -ocmd= | grep 'whatever'`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put that in my OP. Editing now...

Comment: @steeldriver I can't rerun ps on those processes since they were killed -- will have to wait for tomorrow morning. However, ps -ef is supposed to output the full command. The -ocmd= should be implied. I see all the other jobs being displayed with the full command. Only those three jobs had the strange /usr/sbi or /usr/s locations.

Comment: Yes `ps -ef` should output the full command - however the output may get truncated if it is wider than your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

These are 100% normal Ubuntu checks and background processes. If you look into what /usr is it is  a root installation file which is necessary for Ubuntu. This is nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But occupying 36% of my total CPU capacity for over 7 hours doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Cosmo as long as you aren't using your Pc, Ubuntu doesn't "care" about how much CPU it uses. As soon as you use the PC that % will be reduced

Comment: I was working for 30 min to see if it would go down, but no luck.